# pylab error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've used matplotlib / pylab for a few years and love it. Now even the mere import statement

> import pylab as p

or

> import matplotlib

generate the following error. (both in python26 and python26-64, matplotlib 1.1.0)

The only change I'm aware off is that I used (in a different script) the module 'gdspy' (a very nice gds file generating utility for people who make photo masks) just before this happened. Since then it's happening in the simplest examples. My IDE is is Eclipse Indigo.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pd\GDSII\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    import os, re, shutil, subprocess, sys, warnings
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 402, in <module>
    import threading
  File "C:\pd\GDSII\threading.py", line 1, in <module>
    """Thread module emulating a subset of Java's threading model."""
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 287, in <module>
    class ForkAwareLocal(threading.local):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'local'
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 258, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 258, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real error here is indicated in the first traceback, the one that ends with `'module' object has no attribute 'local'`.  It looks to me that when Python encounters a line `import threading`, it is picking up a script `C:\pd\GDSII\threading.py` instead of the correct `C:\Python26\lib\threading.py`.

Your stacktrace suggests to me that Python's `subprocess` module does an `import threading`, and hence Python is presumably picking up this other script instead of the correct [`threading` module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) which it expects to find.  Later on it runs into trouble when one of the multiprocessing modules tries to reference a class which it expected to find in the `threading` module but isn't there.

I don't know for sure what's in `C:\pd\GDSII\threading.py`.  The text `Thread module emulating a subset of Java's threading model` is the same as what appears on line 1 of `C:\Python26\lib\threading.py` on my machine.  Perhaps this errant script is an older version of Python's own threading module that doesn't have the `local` class in it?  Given its location I would guess that it's a part of this gdspy module that you've recently started using.  Does renaming this script to something else (and deleting any `threading.pyc` in the same folder) file help?

Comment: Yes. There is a 'threading.pyc' in my path. It might have been generated by gdspy. I'll inform the author.

Comment: After looking at this for a while I can now see how you figured this out. So thanks for not just solving my problem, but for teaching me how to read this trace properly.